# Unable to upvote or comment on answer

Tags: support, bug

I was able to accept [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/543728/177437), but I am unable to up vote or comment on it. When I click the *Add comment* button I get the following message:

> User does not have permission to comment on this post

But I am reported as logged on (as so in various other SE sites). What is wrong?

Comment: Try again, it worked for me.

Comment: Tried it again and it worked. Strange.